# Python script to go to a link

Tags: python, hyperlink

Good morning, everyone,

I would like to create a script that could find a link and click on it automatically, for example by finding the text of the link.

Could you please help me?

Thanks :)

[my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12KxA.png)

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/py. Selenium is perfect for your usecase.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this. It will find all the links and print the link and the title for all links on the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://example.com/').content, 'lxml').find_all('a', href=True)
[print(x.text, x['href']) for x in soup]
```

If you want to find a specific link, then you have to find an `id` or something identifying like the wrapping `div`'s or other tag's :)

Comment: OP wants to `click on it automatically`

Comment: Well when you have the x.text then you can check if it is the one you are looking for and then click the href to enter the link